# Запретить показ

Tags: html

Нужно запретить показ определённых слов в html, помогите глупому такому))

Comment: Из написанного вами не совсем понятно, что имеется ввиду. По крайней мере с помощью HTML ничего нельзя динамически запретить или сопоставить условию, так как HTML не является языком программирования. Уточните. И вообще, привыкайте писать развернутые вопросы по шаблону - "что надо было получить, что сделал, что не получилось".

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Pqpbp/ 2 варианта: сокрытие слов с оставлением места и без.

Comment: font - тэг этот уже не используется!